# PostgreSQL CASE Function

Tags: function, postgresql, case

I have tried to run this query:

```
CREATE Function sp_test_case () returns void as $$ 
DECLARE
    cont int=(Select MAX(id_fact)from backup_factura);
BEGIN

  while cont>0
  LOOP

    UPDATE backup_factura
    SET tipo= CASE 
            WHEN ((total_fact) <=100) THEN 'X'
            WHEN ((total_fact) <=200) THEN 'Y'
            ELSE 'Z'
           END;

    OUTPUT Deleted.tipo AS BeforeValue,
           Inserted.tipo AS AfterValue
    WHERE id_fact=cont;

    cont:=cont-1;

   END LOOP;

RETURN;   
END;   
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I adapted the code that was originally written in SQL server. Now my doubt is:
Do you know the equivalent of the OUTPUT statement?

The OUTPUT clause is used to display the before and after vacation values.
F.E:

```
OUTPUT Deleted.BusinessEntityID, Deleted.VacationHours AS BeforeValue, 
       Inserted.VacationHours AS AfterValue
```

Any suggestion of what do I need to do in order to make it work?

Thanks in advance for your time & support!

Comment: There is no `OUTPUT Deleted.tipo AS BeforeValue` option in Postgres. Are you looking for the `returning` clause? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html You also didn't declare the `Beforevalue` and `AfterValue` variables. And you are not using them anyways. What exactly are you trying to achieve? As far as I can tell, you can simply use: `UPDATE backup_factura SET tipo = CASE WHEN total_fact <=100 THEN 'X' WHEN total_fact <=200 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'Z' END CASE;` no need for the loop no need for the `where` clause. That will be **much** faster.

Comment: The error in fact is not there (according to PostgreSQL is in other part). Check my edit

Comment: That doesn't matter, there is no `output` clause in Postgres. Check the manual (you are also ending the `update` statement with an `;` then you have the (invalid) `output` clause with a `where` clause that doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

You can do all that without a function or a loop:

This will accomplish exactly the same thing:

```
UPDATE backup_factura 
    SET tipo = CASE 
                 WHEN total_fact <=100 THEN 'X'
                 WHEN total_fact <=200 THEN 'Y'
                 ELSE 'Z'
               END;
```

Strictly speaking you would need a `where id_fact >= 0` to mimic your loop completely - but I'm guessing you don't have negative values in that column.

Note that the **SQL** `case` statement only needs `end`. There is no `end case` in **SQL**: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-conditional.html

Unlike SQL Server, Postgres (and many other DBMS) makes a clear distinction between SQL (the query language) and procedural code (in your case PL/pgSQL). You can't mix the two languages (SQL Server only has a single language: T-SQL).

The `case` statement in PL/pgSQL indeed is terminated using `end case`: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#AEN58362

Not sure what the `output deleted` is supposed to do as you are not deleting anything.

To return the new values from an update statement use the `returning` clause: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I looked for the output and it is a statement from SQL Server.
The OUTPUT clause is used to display the before and after a variable value.

Comment: You should use the Postgres manual, not the SQL Server manual.

Comment: Haha I know, I did edit my post. I am trying to change from SQL Server to this PostgreSQL DBMS

Comment: You can use the `returning` clause to return the updated values. I don't think you can get the "old value" from an update statement.

Comment: Could you teach me in your post how to return the updates values please? I think I will do it that way!

Comment: Check the link to the update statement in the manual. It contains the explanation and examples.